# Change value of an INPUT TEXT checking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, input, checkbox

Why is this not working? It is supposed to work this way: if the checkbox is checked, it should take the content of a variable txt and write it to the input with id of show.

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById('myRadio').checked) {
    var txt = "Done";
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = 'txt';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>If the radio checkbox is checked the text from the variable text is written into input line with the ID of show</p>
        
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()" id="myRadio">

<br>
<br>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="show">
```

Comment: Don't you want to set the value of the text input?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `value` property of the input element, not the `innerHTML`:

```js
function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById('myRadio').checked){
        var txt = "Done";
        document.getElementById("show").value = txt;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("show").value = '';
    }
}
```

```html
<p>If the radio checkbox is checked the text from the variable text is written into input line with the ID of show</p>

<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()" id="myRadio">
<br>
<br>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="show">
```

Comment: Good practice would be to cache `document.getElementById("show")` so you don't have to specify it twice.